# Farseer Physics Engine and the Ms-PL License

Tags: legal, licensing, open-source, velcro-physics-engine

Am I able to produce code for a game which uses the VelcroPhysics engine and release my code under an open source license other than the [Ms-PL](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)?

My concern is with the following section from the license:

> If you distribute any portion of the software in source code form, you
> may do so only under this license by including a complete copy of this
> license with your distribution. If you distribute any portion of the
> software in compiled or object code form, you may only do so under a
> license that complies with this license.

If I do not include Farseer in my source code distribution does this give me an exemption from this clause as I am not distributing the software? My code merely uses its functions. No where in the license does it force you to provide source code for derivative works or linking works, it simply gives you the option of "if you distribute".

Comment: -1 lack of research, there is already a stack overflow question that answers it: [How does MS-PL license work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424307/how-does-ms-pl-license-work). Voting to close, not particularly gamedev-related anyway

Comment: I looked around but google didn't give me that result, or I somehow missed it. It answered my question. Thanks Mark.

Comment: You're welcome Stephen, just google "ms-pl", it's on the first page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Maik Semder for his google-fu this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424334/922745).